# Find the roots of these two polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I have been given these questions for homework:
>
> $x^2 +3x+2$ in $\mathbb Z_5(x)$
>
> and
>
> $x^2 +3x+2 $ in $\mathbb Z_7(x)$

Clearly in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ the roots are $-1$ and $-2$ by factorizing the equation getting;

$$x^2+3x+2=(x+1)(x+2)$$

Would I be correct if I said the roots of $(x+1)(x+2)$ in $\mathbb Z_5$ is $4$ and $3$ (because $-1$ and $-2$ are congruent to $4$ and $3$ in $\mathbb Z_5$)

And the roots of $(x+1)(x+2)$ in $\mathbb Z_7$ is $6$ and $5$ (for the same reason)?

I think I am doing this wrong.

Comment: No you are correct, note that the roots in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ are also $8$ and $9$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$f(x)=x^2+3x+2$$

In both these cases you are working over a finite field, and since the polynomials are quadratic, the factorization $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ satisfies $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=0$. So, just go looking for roots.

For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ you compute
\begin{align}
f(0)&=2\\
f(1)&=1\\
f(2)&=2\\
f(3)&=20=0\\
f(4)&=40=0
\end{align}
Therefore, $f(x)=(x-3)(x-4)=(x+2)(x+1)\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. Working over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is similar.